# Nginx Change Request from PUT to POST

Tags: rest, nginx

I'm using nginx for a PHP REST API that I'm working on. To be fully REST-ful, I'm using `PUT`/`DELETE` requests where appropriate. However, PHP doesn't parse the post body on `PUT` requests - which I need for this particular scenario.

I had considered parsing it myself, but a) I'd rather let PHP do it in C as it's considerably faster than any implementation I could come up with in PHP and b) there are a lot of edge cases that people have already spent a lot of time working around - I'd rather not duplicate those efforts.

On the API side, I have already added support to read the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header and use that when available over the actual verb.

All I'm looking for now is a way, in nginx, to take a `PUT` request, and change it to a `POST` request with that header set.

I feel ike I have looked all over the place but can't find a solution. Anything would be helpful (even if you recommend a different parsing technique so I don't have to deal with this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx only informs FastCGI of the request method via `REQUEST_METHOD` param. So you may simply override the value and report anything you want to PHP. You'll have to declare another variable in your Nginx configuration, let's name it `$fcgi_method`, based on the original request method:

```
map $request_method $fcgi_method {
  default $request_method;
  PUT POST;
}
```

(note that `map` sections should be at `http` level, i.e. the same configuration level as `server` blocks)

Then you may use it in your location like so:

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD  $fcgi_method;
```

It's important that this snippet is after typical `include fastcgi_params` or alike.

Comment: Wow - you're absolutely right. This is what I get from coming from a world of Apache.

Comment: This doesn't work: nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_param" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/xxxxx:x

Comment: @Philio oh, you're right. I've corrected the answer

Comment: That's probably a better way to do it, although having read the question (I found this searching for a way to get Nginx to recognise the X-HTTP-Method-Override header), this is probably an incredibly hacky solution to what is clearly programming error in the first place. PHP has no problem getting the body of a PUT request.

Comment: @Philio Say it to the OP via a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth pointing out in case anyone else considers this method for processing a PUT request in PHP (or any other request method that isn't populated into some global $_WHATEVER array to make life easy) that the correct way to get the body of a put request is to read the contents of `php://input`.

Something like this should work:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```